# Dreamweaver CS4: Autospell check in code view?

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm an Java eclipse user thats doing web development in coldfusion in Dreamweaver. In eclipse, it checks your spelling as you type, is there a similar functionality in dreamweaver's code view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean spell-check the code functions then there is sort of a way.  In Edit | Preferences | Code Hints you can enable hinting which will kinda/sorta provide a spell check function.  If you get the function correct, you'll get the hinting.  Caveat, not all functions work with CS4.

If you mean spell-check text, then no.  DW won't do spell-as-you-go in Code or Design View.  In fact, it won't do spell check at all in Code View...you will have to be Split or Design view to run the command.